# UINavBar stretch image to edges

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I've tried to use an image for my navigation bar background but can't get it to reach the edges:

[image]

The image sizes I've set are 320 x 44 and 640 x 88.

This is the code to set it it:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will apply for whole app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"];
    [navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: @Robert Remember to mark his answer as correct if it helped you

Comment: I will as soon as SO allows.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png" forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It does, thanks. Turns out Viktor's answer works best but yours is good too so have an upvote.